# RSpec with Fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures

I am new to Rails. I have studied fixtures in Rails. Forgive me, I could not understand which fixtures exactly I have to include in a spec for a controller. Sometimes I have seen people to include more than one fixtures in a spec. So I basically want to know how do I understand whether to include a fixture in a spec or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixtures should not be used. Use factories

Comment: I have not found any good tutorial about how to use factorygirl in writing a spec for a controller.

Comment: All FG does is help you create instances of classes. What kind of tutorial are you looking for?

Comment: I want a tutorial where there are examples of using factory girl with rspec.

Comment: I recommend http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book